# Grails 2.4.4 Project Build and Run Error in IntelliJIdea Ultimate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grails, groovy

I am not able to run the Grails 2.4.4 project directly from the "Run" button from IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate IDE.

```
    Resource compiler: Error: Couldn't copy [/project-path/grails-app/i18n/messages_de.properties] to [/out/production/project-name/messages_de.properties]
java.io.IOException: Couldn't copy [/project-path/grails-app/i18n/messages_de.properties] to [/out/production/project-name/messages_de.properties]
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.performCopy(FileUtil.java:425)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.copyContent(FileUtil.java:415)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.FSOperations.copy(FSOperations.java:476)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.resources.ResourcesBuilder.copyResource(ResourcesBuilder.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.resources.ResourcesBuilder.lambda$build$0(ResourcesBuilder.java:67)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.fs.BuildFSState.processFilesToRecompile(BuildFSState.java:375)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder$6.processDirtyFiles(IncProjectBuilder.java:1257)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.resources.ResourcesBuilder.build(ResourcesBuilder.java:56)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.resources.ResourcesBuilder.build(ResourcesBuilder.java:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTarget(IncProjectBuilder.java:1262)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1162)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1299)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:1114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:885)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:467)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:197)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:150)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:348)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:175)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:218)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is the build error I get.
[image: i18n files not able to copy]

Basically the i18n files mentioned above are the files that are not getting copied into the production folder

```
Resource compiler: Error: Couldn't copy [/project-path/grails-app/i18n/messages_de.properties] to [/out/production/project-name/messages_de.properties]
```

I am restarting the project every single time I make a small change in the project and it is as good as taking ages to build a single element API which can be done in 2 mins.

Comment: `I am restarting the project every single time I make a small change in the project` do you mean restarting helps? Looking at the error - it seems that the cause if that some program locks files or the process IDE launches to compiler the project. Do you have antivirus/firewall? Please try with it disabled or make sure that IDE [settings/caches directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519), the IDE installation home and project files are excluded from the scan.

Comment: There is no Antivirus or Firewall, I am on plain MacOS 12.4

Comment: Also the restarting of project is more towards reloading the code into memory every single time I make a change. The IDE just doesn't reload the changes or aka `hot swap` the codes.

Comment: It is interesting that the error message indicates that `/out/production/project-name/messages_de.properties` is mentioned as the output.  Normally that directory would be relative to your project root instead of the root of the file system.  It is possible the IDE is reporting that in a way that is misleading, but it looks like that might be relevant.

Comment: The error comes when I try to run the project but when I just build it, it builds the `.war` file completely.

Comment: Do you have write permissions to `/out/production/project-name/messages_de.properties`?

Comment: Thanks for the assisatance @JeffScottBrown 
I resolved the file copy issue with Resources copy restrictions lifted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the file copy issue with broadening the Compiler Resource Copy Restrictions.

[image: Resource not copying issue resolve Settings in IntelliJ Idea]